# Flex. Replace the selected text in Text Input

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, textinput

How do I to make a function that replaces the selected text in text INPUT on the symbol of the selected one from each list?

Thank you

Comment: I have a text INPUT
I've got to be the mouse to select text. for example my name and replace it with the names that are on the list<s:TextInput 
  x="422" 
  y="270" 
  width="300" text="Hello Sergi, How are you ? :)" id="myTextInput"/>

Comment: In other words, he wants to do something in flex that you can do with excel and word (god, i hate myself for saying that), Where you link a certain table to a place in the letter. (for example a campaign where personalised advertisement is sent: Hi <Name Here>, I've got a deal for you.    He wants to select the text with his mouse in the text-input and then press a button to replace the selected text (not all the text).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this sample it may be help full thanks

**Explaination** 
If you type "Imran $" it will replace it with "Imran Hello" on text change Event you may also use any other event

**Code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                private var lst:Array = new Array(
                                                {msg:"Hello", data:"$"},
                                                {msg:"Bye", data:"@"}
                                                );
                private function textchanged(event:Event):void
                {

                    var len:int = txt.text.length;
                    if(len!=0)
                    {
                        var msg:String = getMessage(txt.text.charAt(len-1)); 
                        if(msg!= null)
                        {
                            txt.removeEventListener(Event.CHANGE,textchanged);
txt.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE,updateComplete);
                            txt.text = txt.text.slice(0, len-1) + " "+ msg;
                        }
                    }
                }

                private function updateComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
                {
                    txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,textchanged);
                }

                private function getMessage(data:String):String
                {
                    var msg:String = null;
                    for each(var obj:Object in lst)
                    {
                        if(obj.data == data)
                        {
                            msg = obj.msg;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return msg;
                }
            ]]>
        </mx:Script>
        <mx:TextInput id="txt" change="textchanged(event)" />

    </mx:Application>
```

Comment: I do not know very well English, I from Russia

But you do not understand me .... I have to do the replacement of the selected text from my text INPUT

<s:TextInput id="MyText" text="Hello Sergii" />

I select "Sergii" and when you click on any name to the list .. My name is replaced by the selection!

Answer (score 1):

This Sampe Replace selected text in TextInput by List Text on Clicking List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            [Bindable]
            private var arr:Array = new Array(
                                            {msg:"Hello", data:"$"},
                                            {msg:"Bye", data:"@"}
                                            );

            private function replaceSelection(event:MouseEvent):void
            {


                    var obj:Object = lst.selectedItem;
                    var selStr:int = txt.selectionBeginIndex;
                    var selEnd:int = txt.selectionEndIndex;

                    if((lst.selectedItem != null)&&(selStr!=selEnd))
                    {
                         txt.text = txt.text.substring(0,selStr)+lst.selectedItem.msg.toString()+txt.text.substring(selEnd,txt.text.length)
                    }
            }           

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:TextInput id="txt" />
        <mx:List id="lst" dataProvider="{arr}" labelField="msg" click="{replaceSelection(event)}"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

**EDITED**: Modification needed Embed XML File as data source

XML File "messages.xml" {Its in same/root folder of Flex Source}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item><msg>Hello</msg></item>
    <item><msg>Bye</msg></item>
</root>
```

Embeding XML File in Flex Application, using MXML component

```
<mx:XML id="xml" source="messages.xml" />
```

Modification in List Control, for working with XML

```
<mx:List id="lst" dataProvider="{xml.item}" labelField="msg" click="{replaceSelection(event)}"/>
```

**Note**: No other changes required in Program

Hopefully this will help

Comment: Imran, and can be made ​​to the data loaded from the XML file?

Comment: yes it can be, i have modified ans, its embeding XML file in SWF on compile time. hopes thats helps